# Google MapFragment is blank (white) with Could not find class 'maps.j.k'

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to build the official [android google map api v2](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html) sample on a (gingerbread 2.3.5) phone .
I added `android-support-v4.jar` to official sample project.

I took the sample from the official tutorial in `<android-sdk>/extras/google-play-services/samples/maps`

I copied the sample app in Eclipse, reference the `google-play-services_lib` project as an Android library, and build the whole thing with the Android SDK 4.1.2 (api 16).

Unfortunately, ahen I launch the app the map is blank and I don't have any exception or message.
The only thing I got are those suspicious lines in the logcat :

```
    Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/a/du; (411)                     
    Link of class 'Lmaps/a/du;' failed                                    
    Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/a/ej; (2363)                    
    Link of class 'Lmaps/a/ej;' failed                                    
    Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/j/k; (2379)                     
    Link of class 'Lmaps/j/k;' failed
```

ERR  Could not find class 'maps.j.k', referenced from method maps.y.ae.a
        VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3571 (Lmaps/j/k;) in Lmaps/y/ae;

I suspect that my project structure in eclipse 3.8 is somewhat messed up.

I tried the following things (even the most idiotic) to no avail.

### 1. Invalid api key ?

I generated a "debug.keystore" with keytool and updated the eclipse preference (Android/Build/Keystore).
Of course, I registered that new keystore/SHA1 and get a new api key that I used in the AndroidManifest file

### 2. Wrong project target ?

I tried to build my two projects with the following targets :

- Android 4.2.1
- Google Api 4.2.1

### 3. adding google-play-services_lib as a project dependency

I tried to add google-play-services_lib as a project dependency on top of being added as an android library in the demo build path.
And tick the matching export checkbox.

### 4. test google maps api v2 on the phone

I downloaded [trulia real estate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trulia.android) app that is said to use the v2 api on the phone to be sure that the phone is compatible with the new api

Here is the manifest for the sample app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <!-- End of copy. -->
    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/demo_title" >
        <!-- You must insert your own Google Maps for Android API v2 key in here. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXXX" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BasicMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/basic_map" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/camera_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".EventsDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/events_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GroundOverlayDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/groundoverlay_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LayersDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/layers_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationSourceDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/locationsource_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MarkerDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/marker_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".OptionsDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/options_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PolygonDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/polygon_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PolylineDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/polyline_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ProgrammaticDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/programmatic_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".TileOverlayDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/tile_overlay_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UiSettingsDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/uisettings_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RawMapViewDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/raw_mapview_demo" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RetainMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/retain_map" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MultiMapDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/multi_map_demo" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here are some screenshots of my project structure/build path.

[image: Project structure]

[image: Target and libraries]

[image: Build path]

Comment: do you have the lib project on dropbox? did you tried to put it on a local folder?

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu Well, a dropbox folder is a local folder :) Besides, I always shutdown dropbox when I code. 
And I launch dropbox once, at the end of the day for an online backup of my files.

Comment: The "error" messages Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/a/du; (411) do not denote errors.
Even when the application works fine, you get those messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem (all configurations the same, maps.j.k stuff in the logcat). However, for me choosing Google APIs as build target solved it. But that was Google APIs 4.2, so I suggest that you install the update and try with the more recent target.

Comment: I just did the test, and it failed the same way (maps.j.k).
1. Did you use google api for both the sample project and the google-play-services_lib library ?
2. Are you sure you haven't done something else ? 

3. What was the phone you were using for your tests (model and android version) ?

4. Would it be feasible to share your project files (removing all the sensitive parts) ? I'm really struggling on a deadline now, and I'm desperate.

Comment: @Carl, 1. I only use Google APIs for the main project. I haven’t touched services_lib, just imported it to the workspace (via copy). Now looked and it says it’s using Android 2.3.3 as a build target. 2. I tried to remove all imports related to Maps API v1, but as I said, had to bring Google APIs back. Don’t know if it counts. 3. HTC Wildfire S, 2.3.5. Also tried on HTC One X and it worked from the start. 4. [link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/k0wzre) — manifest, .project file and example layout with map.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, it doesn't change anything. By the way google-play-services_lib library doesn't come with the eclipse project files (.project, .classpath), so it has to be recreated. And I could have make errors while doing it.

Comment: @Carl, I didn’t have to recreate anything! In Eclipse Project Explorer, right click → import → android/existing android code into workspace → click next, choose the lib folder (SDK/extras/...) and tick “copy into workspace”.

Answer (score 15):

I think maybe you make something wrong when you apply the api KEY.
I have the same problem, and at last I found that I turn on the incorrect service. at https://code.google.com/apis/console/,

There are `Google Maps API v2` and `Google Maps Android API v2`.

You should use `Google Maps Android API v2`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I *did* that rookie mistake the first time I tried the api. Fortunately, I found out on my own :)

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by changing de *targetSdkVersion* with de last *targetSdkVersion* avaiable, at the *AndroiMainfest.xml* file.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using ProGuard? Usually class names like "a", "b", etc. are a result of ProGuard obfuscating class names, and maybe the Maps API breaks when that happens. If that's the case, you will either have to disable ProGuard or add some `-keep` lines to your proguard.cfg file. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9158373/1207921) shows what those lines might look like.

Comment: Well, I have the issue when I build/deploy my app from Eclipse. AFAIK, proguard is not used in that case (only used when export your apk).
I suspect that this class belongs to maps.jar who comes with Google API.

Comment: @karakuri, this answer is not helpful, or accurate. The post you link to 1. clearly states that obfuscation wouldn't be a problem for map rendering and 2. refers to Version 1 of the Maps API, not the (current) Version 2 that this question is about.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was due to 2 issues

1. on my phone the latest Google Maps app was not installed (in fact there was no google maps at all)
2. I didnt have all the required permissions set in my manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

As documented in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html --this is the link for the adt bundle in android..try downloading this and start over again..maybe there's a problem with your ADT.

Comment: this is a comment, not a self contained answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the console API you've enabled Google Maps **Android** API v2

Comment: This would be better as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with same issue.  I tried to implement the com.example.mapdemo and had a heck of a time.

I copied the code of the BasicMapActivity to a clean new project and made the Libraries look as above.

Basically, I couldn't get either to work.  I got the "Authorization failure" error in the debugger.

Then, today, I prepared new keys specifically for each project with the specific com.example.xxx after the semicolon when preparing the key in the Google Console.

I did Project->Clean at every step.

I ran it in debugger first, then just Run.  And, if I remember, a few times after making the change to the manifest.

Then, finally, they worked.  It seemed, in the end, to require a key for each specific project.

Comment: Found this:  https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw      VERY HELPFUL

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. When you use the Google APIs Console to create your API key, be sure to append ;com.example.mapdemo to the SHA1 fingerprint. (I was using something else more appropriate for another app I'm currently developing.) What clued me in on this solution was an authorization error in the LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added LocationSource Interface so I can get location data but i forgot to add :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

at Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use separate keys for debug and release version of the app!

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried everything, try to uninstall and reinstall again your app: on my phone (S3 mini), after the first launch with the wrong key, I corrected it, but it didn't work until a complete uninstallation.
Maybe some sort of caching is used.