# Android Google Maps Version 2 Not Displaying

Tags: android-maps-v2

I know there have been a ton of posts on this topic, but I am puzzled.  I have (2) different phones that I am testing my App on.  The Google Map (Support Map Fragment) displays fine on each device, but only when I target each device directly from Eclipse (using the cable).  If I create an APK file (via Exporting through Eclipse) and install the APK file that way on the device, the app runs fine, but the maps don't display (only zoom buttons appear).  Here is the LogCat:

```
03-11 18:02:02.710: W/dalvikvm(31316): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/s; (427)
03-11 18:02:02.710: W/dalvikvm(31316): Link of class 'Lmaps/p/s;' failed
03-11 18:02:02.710: W/dalvikvm(31316): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/y/bo; (3820)
03-11 18:02:02.710: W/dalvikvm(31316): Link of class 'Lmaps/y/bo;' failed
03-11 18:02:02.710: W/dalvikvm(31316): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/i/k; (4208)
03-11 18:02:02.710: W/dalvikvm(31316): Link of class 'Lmaps/i/k;' failed
03-11 18:02:02.710: E/dalvikvm(31316): Could not find class 'maps.i.k', referenced from method maps.z.ag.a
03-11 18:02:02.710: W/dalvikvm(31316): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3540 (Lmaps/i/k;) in Lmaps/z/ag;
```

I used the debug key, as I am just testing for now.  Obviously each phone is set up correctly (Google Play Services etc.), which leads me to believe I am not exporting the APK file properly from Eclipse.  Help!!

Comment: Same here! Did you get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.  I was not signing the app properly when exporting the APK file.  The debug keystore must be used - usually located in the ".android" folder in your user folder.  The password is "android".  If you enter everything correctly, you should be able to select the "androiddebugkey" from the "Alias".  The password for that is also "android".

Of course when you download the app directly from eclipse to your phone (via the cable) and test it, the app is automatically 'signed' in debug mode, that is why it worked in that scenario.