# Google Maps not appearing Android App -- Actionbarsherlock + Google Play services

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I am trying to implement Google Maps API V2, but the maps are not appearing. Fragment appears with +/- sign for zoom and Google written on the left hand side.

I wrote a simple code which should just show the maps. It shows the authentication failure in the logcat, but I am 100% sure that I did the right steps that are :

1. Started the Google Android API V2 Service
2. Obtained the Key, using SHA1;com.example.action (Package Name) of my project.

XML file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Java file:

```
package com.example.action;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.action"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <!-- Specify the correct minSDK and targetSDK versions. -->
    <!-- Google Maps related permissions -->
    <permission android:name="com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
 
    <!-- Network connectivity permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 
    <!-- Access Google based webservices -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
 
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>   

       
       
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
        
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCIrEGMEBSP8bU2jorUlmmPLVpVYngyPUE"/>
 
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />  
 
        
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.action.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the app shows this:

[image]

Logcat:

```
03-21 15:37:05.101: D/dalvikvm(8393): GC_EXPLICIT freed 16K, 43% free 4308K/7431K, external 592K/1042K, paused 51ms
03-21 15:41:41.140: I/ApplicationPackageManager(8685): cscCountry is not German : INU
03-21 15:41:41.187: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6231: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
03-21 15:41:41.187: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
03-21 15:41:41.187: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
03-21 15:41:41.203: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4872: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F
03-21 15:41:41.203: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
03-21 15:41:41.203: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F
03-21 15:41:41.203: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4874: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getTranslationY ()F
03-21 15:41:41.203: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
03-21 15:41:41.203: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getTranslationY ()F
03-21 15:41:41.203: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4878: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
03-21 15:41:41.203: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
03-21 15:41:41.203: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
03-21 15:41:41.203: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4886: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setTranslationY (F)V
03-21 15:41:41.203: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
03-21 15:41:41.210: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setTranslationY (F)V
03-21 15:41:41.218: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4536: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getAlpha ()F
03-21 15:41:41.218: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
03-21 15:41:41.218: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getAlpha ()F
03-21 15:41:41.218: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4547: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationX ()F
03-21 15:41:41.218: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
03-21 15:41:41.218: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationX ()F
03-21 15:41:41.218: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4548: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationY ()F
03-21 15:41:41.218: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
03-21 15:41:41.218: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationY ()F
03-21 15:41:41.218: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4572: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setAlpha (F)V
03-21 15:41:41.218: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
03-21 15:41:41.218: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setAlpha (F)V
03-21 15:41:41.218: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4577: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationX (F)V
03-21 15:41:41.226: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
03-21 15:41:41.226: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationX (F)V
03-21 15:41:41.226: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4578: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationY (F)V
03-21 15:41:41.226: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
03-21 15:41:41.226: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationY (F)V
03-21 15:41:41.250: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 7092: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
03-21 15:41:41.250: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
03-21 15:41:41.250: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.dispatchHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
03-21 15:41:41.250: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4876: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
03-21 15:41:41.250: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
03-21 15:41:41.320: D/dalvikvm(8685): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
03-21 15:41:41.320: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 47
03-21 15:41:41.320: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
03-21 15:41:41.320: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
03-21 15:41:41.429: D/dalvikvm(8685): GC_CONCURRENT freed 212K, 46% free 3051K/5639K, external 419K/517K, paused 4ms+4ms
03-21 15:41:41.632: D/dalvikvm(8685): GC_CONCURRENT freed 130K, 43% free 3440K/5959K, external 419K/517K, paused 4ms+19ms
03-21 15:41:41.750: W/dalvikvm(8685): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/aj/r; (667)
03-21 15:41:41.750: W/dalvikvm(8685): Link of class 'Lmaps/aj/r;' failed
03-21 15:41:41.750: W/dalvikvm(8685): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/ay/an; (6038)
03-21 15:41:41.750: W/dalvikvm(8685): Link of class 'Lmaps/ay/an;' failed
03-21 15:41:41.750: W/dalvikvm(8685): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/c/i; (6269)
03-21 15:41:41.750: W/dalvikvm(8685): Link of class 'Lmaps/c/i;' failed
03-21 15:41:41.750: E/dalvikvm(8685): Could not find class 'maps.c.i', referenced from method maps.e.al.a
03-21 15:41:41.750: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 6474 (Lmaps/c/i;) in Lmaps/e/al;
03-21 15:41:41.750: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0091
03-21 15:41:41.804: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x0093-00a0 in Lmaps/e/al;.a (Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;Z)Lmaps/e/al;
03-21 15:41:41.835: I/ApplicationPackageManager(8685): cscCountry is not German : INU
03-21 15:41:41.890: D/dalvikvm(8685): GC_CONCURRENT freed 239K, 42% free 3710K/6343K, external 419K/517K, paused 3ms+5ms
03-21 15:41:42.148: D/dalvikvm(8685): GC_CONCURRENT freed 346K, 42% free 3929K/6663K, external 419K/517K, paused 4ms+5ms
03-21 15:41:42.320: D/dalvikvm(8685): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 168K, 40% free 4024K/6663K, external 444K/517K, paused 62ms
03-21 15:41:42.546: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4443: Landroid/view/View;.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState ()V
03-21 15:41:42.546: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0056
03-21 15:41:42.578: D/libEGL(8685): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_hgl.so
03-21 15:41:42.585: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4932: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.getAlpha ()F
03-21 15:41:42.585: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
03-21 15:41:42.585: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.getAlpha ()F
03-21 15:41:42.585: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4935: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.getTranslationX ()F
03-21 15:41:42.585: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
03-21 15:41:42.585: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.getTranslationX ()F
03-21 15:41:42.585: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4947: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
03-21 15:41:42.593: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
03-21 15:41:42.593: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
03-21 15:41:42.593: W/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4954: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.setTranslationX (F)V
03-21 15:41:42.593: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
03-21 15:41:42.593: D/dalvikvm(8685): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.setTranslationX (F)V
03-21 15:41:42.601: D/BRCM_EGL(8685): eglCreateContext() context: 0x1a0868, VC context 1, Thread 8706
03-21 15:41:42.609: D/BRCM_EGL(8685): eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x1a08d8, VC surface: 1, Thread: 8706
03-21 15:41:42.609: D/BRCM_EGL(8685): eglMakeCurrent(0x1a0868, 0x1a08d8, 0x1a08d8) Thread: 8706
03-21 15:41:49.171: D/dalvikvm(8685): GC_CONCURRENT freed 233K, 39% free 4237K/6855K, external 826K/1042K, paused 4ms+6ms
03-21 15:41:52.007: E/Google Maps Android API(8685): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
03-21 15:41:52.015: E/Google Maps Android API(8685): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.action, API Key: AIzaSyCIrEGMEBSP8bU2jorUlmmPLVpVYngyPUE, Certificate Fingerprint: A76E6DC98764157ACBA297873AE9E462707E0436
03-21 15:41:52.023: I/Google Maps Android API(8685): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
03-21 15:41:52.882: D/BRCM_EGL(8685): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 8706
03-21 15:41:52.882: D/BRCM_EGL(8685): eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x1a08d8, android window 0x1a9f50, Thread: 8706
03-21 15:42:07.554: E/Google Maps Android API(8685): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
03-21 15:42:41.500: D/dalvikvm(8685): GC_CONCURRENT freed 681K, 43% free 4239K/7367K, external 592K/1042K, paused 4ms+4ms
```

Comment: see this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145789/google-maps-works-fine-on-android-but-i-still-get-an-error-could-not-find-class][1]
its the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It is API key issue. Create the SHA using default debug keystore and get the API key and create the APK again on the same system.