# Google Maps V2 maps always blank

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to implement Google's new api v2 on Android 2.3.3 with the debug.keystore

What ever i do i get a blank map..

**Code:**

```
public class MainFragment extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    }       
}
```

**activity_map.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.WhosAround.MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.WhosAround"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.WhosAround.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.WhosAround.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.WhosAround.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.WhosAround.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:name="com.WhosAround.AppVariables"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/questionmark"
        android:label="Who&apos;s Around?"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <!-- android:name="com.WhosAround.Activities.PreLoader" -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainFragment"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my_key_generated_from_google" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Why did you wrapped the SupportMapFragment with FrameLayout? Try to have the fragment only.

Answer (score 1):

From some reason, it suddenly works...
Maybe the Google Console servers takes time to update...

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you change computers your debug api key becomes void. I had to generate one for my laptop and one for my pc at home and switch between the two. This is because it uses the pc mac address to validate the code. If you did not change pc's you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747455/google-mapfragment-is-blank-white-with-could-not-find-class-maps-j-k) question.